# Simplify a confusing matrix

Tags: matrices, inner-products, tensor-products

I'm having a problem of my own on Numerical Analysis, just some matrix transformation that I'm dealing with. I need to reduce this matrix to simpler form of dot product "$\cdot$" or cross product “$\times$” or tensor product "$\otimes$", since the double sum at each component makes calculation very difficult.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_j(x_i) &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_j(x_{i+\tfrac{1}{n}}) &
\dots &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_j(x_{i+\tfrac{n}{n}}) \\
%
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{1}{n}}(x_i) &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{1}{n}}(x_{i+\tfrac{1}{n}}) &
\dots &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{1}{n}}(x_{i+\tfrac{n}{n}}) \\
%
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
%
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{n}{n}}(x_i) &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{n}{n}}(x_{i+\tfrac{1}{n}}) &
\dots &
\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{m_i}\sum_{j=0}^{m_j} g_{j+\tfrac{n}{n}}(x_{i+\tfrac{n}{n}})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In the above matrix, $g_{\alpha}(x)$ is some arbitrary function and $x_{\lambda}$ is given ($\alpha,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$).

Can someone give me an idea on how I can do this?

Comment: Several $\frac{n}{n}$ are typos?

Comment: @user376343 No it’s not, every column the subscript of $g$ range from $j$ to $j+\frac{n}{n}=j+1$ with jump step $\frac{1}{n}$, same for every row with the subscript of $x$ but start from $i$.